# Grub : Ubuntu 20.04 Dual boot with Phoenix OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, 20.04

I've downloaded Phoenix OS and extracted it to root folder as per the community guidelines.

I've added grub entry as following :

```
menuentry “PhoenixOS-ROC” {
linux /PhoenixOS-ROC/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet SRC=/PhoenixOS-ROC DATA=/data VGA=788
initrd /PhoenixOS-ROC/initrd.img
}
```

Everything seems fine as per the community guidelines and I've double-checked every step.

But, **I am getting the following error while I select "PhoenixOS-ROC" in the grub menu on restart**.

> The ntfs partitions /dev/block/nvme0 cannot be mounted, error number
> is 18. Found at /dev/nvme0n1p1

Following are the fdisk -l result :

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLW512HMJP-000L2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7B54F26C-EFE6-4F95-A87C-CABB2EE1544B

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048  976777215 976775168 465.8G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 976777216  978731007   1953792   954M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3 978731008 1000214527  21483520  10.3G Linux swap
```

No idea what I am missing, Please suggest.

Comment: It's trying to mount a nonexistent partition/device.  You have no NTFS partitions.

Comment: Try adding a new line with `search --file --set=root /PhoenixOS-ROC/kernel` after `menuentry "PhoenixOS-ROC" {`

Comment: @ThomasWard `/dev/nvme0n1p1` could be a NTFS partition (the partition type could be wrong in the partition table)

Comment: @MaxSilvester possible, but the fact that it states that it's an EFI system partition and there's an "ntfs partition could not be mounted" issue... :p

Comment: This is sounding more like a Phoenix OS issue than an Ubuntu issue, I ran a search on the net for the error message and there's a number of people who have had this error.  Also, if Ubuntu overwrote Phoenix OS then that means you used the wrong install configurations set to 'overwrite' everything.

Comment: @MaxSilvester Still not working bro :(